# What is this yellow line with a dot at the end?

Tags: 3d-view, interface

I think I have entered a sequence of commands as a mistake and now a yellow line appears in top of my selection.
I don't know what it is for or how to enable/disable it.

I have tried closing the editor but it keeps appearing.

[image]

Comment: Just to add - this looks like the *Edge Slide* tool :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've simply activated a tool from the toolbox on the left. You can see wich tool you have selected by the blue background on it.
If you don't see that toolbox, simply hit T while your cursor is hovering over your 3D viewport, or drag the little arrow on the top-left part of the viewport.

The default tool is Rectangle Selection (the top-most one), click it.

[image]